# Posting check boxes into MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, checkbox

What I need to do is insert whatever is checked by the user into the table that we created in our database.  I am able to get the data stored into an array, but then I cant get it stored into the database.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="partType[]" value="GenericBreakPads" /> Generic Break Pads 
    <input type="checkbox" name="partType[]" value="Air_Conditioning_Compressor" /> Air Conditioning Compressor 
    <input type="checkbox" name="partType[]" value="Generic_Battery" /> Generic Battery <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="partType[]" value="Carburetor" /> Carburetor       
    <input type="checkbox" name="partType[]" value="Engine_Balance_Shaft" /> Engine Balance Shaft             
    <input type="checkbox" name="partType[]" value="Engine_Cylinder" /> Engine Cylinder                 
    </form>
```

I have tried serialize but that wasn't very helpful due to the way it stored it into the table.

```
$theParts=serialize($_POST['partType']); //takes the data from a post operation...
$query=INSERT INTO parts VALUES('$partType');
```

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: how exactly do you want to store the data? in a single column? in multiple columns, as a m2m relationship?

Comment: You really wanted to type: `$theParts=`**`mysql_real_escape_string`**`(serialize($_POST['partType'])); //takes the data from a post operation...
$query=INSERT INTO parts VALUES('$partType'); ` right, right?

Comment: You wrote `$theParts`, not `$partType`. Discrepancy!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO parts VALUES("'. mysql_real_escape_string($partType) .'");';
```

Answer (score 0):

you really should loop through the checkbox results. 
ie

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($partType);$i++) {
  //insert record into database using $partType[$i]
}
```

you can then insert the data on discrete rows.

However if you really must store in a single field then you could also just implode the array into a comma seperated string. you can then insert that string into your database field

```
implode("," $partType);
```

This is breaking good database design/usage though as its no longer normalised as your storing more than 1 item inside a single database field

[implode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Hope that helps